# App Script is not currently working, supposed to take Google Sheet Tab, duplicate tab, and save the duplicated tab as a PDF in a folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In my Apps Script, the script is supposed to trigger the "Template" tab of a Google Sheet to duplicate itself and save as a PDF whenever the range C17:O22 of the "Template" tab is changed.

```
'function onChange(e) {var sheet = e.source.getSheetByName("Template");var range = e.range;// Check if the change occurred in the "Template" tab and within the specified range if (sheet && range && sheet.getName() === "Template" && range.getRow() >= 17 && range.getRow() <= 22 && range.getColumn() >= 3 && range.getColumn() <= 15) {
// Duplicate the "Template" tab
var newSheetName = "Template_" + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
sheet.copyTo(sheet.getParent()).setName(newSheetName);

// Move the duplicated tab to the specified folder
var folderId = "folderID"; // Replace with the folder ID where you want to save the PDF
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
var newSheet = sheet.getParent().getSheetByName(newSheetName);
folder.createFile(newSheet.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf')).setName(newSheetName + ".pdf");
sheet.getParent().deleteSheet(newSheet);}}`
```

When C17:O22 is changed, the duplicate tab is created, but it does not save as a PDF. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: There is no e.range in the event object `{"authMode":"FULL","changeType":"FORMAT","source":{},"triggerUid":"","user":{"email":"","nickname":"cooper"}}` Also onChange() is not a simple trigger so you have to create it as an insstallable trigger